# JS - jQuery parameter $

Tags: jquery, parameters

**Q:** What is difference between

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...}
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {...}
```

I know that **$** is "parameter" of function. But what that **`$`** means in this example ?

Please explain also with some usage examples.

Comment: first one you are sure than inside ready handler $ refers to jQuery as jQuery is passed as first parameter Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L78Fh/

Answer (score -1):

function($) means you are passing jQuery (or other library, that uses $) object.

Comment: `jQuery(function($) { })` is never going to pass in "other libraries". In this use, it is explicitly for obtaining a handle to `jQuery`.

Comment: And what if i write my own library on and use '$' too?

Comment: @JustinasJurciukonis still only jQuery will be passed, $ became local